# Can I get original Query from PGresult* object in Postgres?

Tags: api, postgresql, libpq

```
mConn = PQconnectdb( conninfo );
const char* pQuery = "SELECT X FROM Y...";
PGresult* stmt = PQexec( mConn, pQuery );
```

can I do this?

```
char * original_query = Take( stmt );
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `PGresult` structure does not contain that information.  You need to save it yourself somehow.

Answer (score 1):

See [`current_query()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-info.html) and its source code.